# how to get images into blackberry and set an onClick listener?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I'm rather new to programming Blackberries and was wondering if anybody knows of a tutorial or a snippet about how to load an image into the screen and set an onClick listener to it?

edit, got this far:

```
ButtonField btf1 = new ButtonField("Fine!");
ButtonField btf2 = new ButtonField("Great!");
RichTextField rtf = new RichTextField("HELLO, HOW ARE YOU?");

Bitmap LOGO = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("1.png");
BitmapField LogoBmpField = new BitmapField(LOGO);

HelloWorldScreen()
{        
    setTitle("My First App");
    add(rtf);
    add(btf1);
    add(btf2);
    add(LogoBmpField);
}
```

Thanks!

edit: by the way, how should interfaces be made for blackberry? simply by

```
ButtonField btf1 = new ButtonField("Fine!");
add(btf1);
```

Or is there some more visible way, such as in XML for android?

One more thing, how to I change or set properties of some object. Say I want to change the title of my button- btf1.(expecting list of available properties to appear ) doesn't give anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your image in your res folder and try this;

```
Bitmap bmpLogo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("yourImage.jpg");
BitmapField logo = new BitmapField(bmpLogo){
    protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time)
    {   
        // Your onclick code here
        return true;
    }
};
add(logo);
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't work for the BitmapField, yet works for the ButtonField. :)

Comment: oh, looks like the BitmapField isn't trackwheelClick, is there some kind on onscreenClick method?

Comment: Not that I know of, not sure why this doesn't work, BitmapField is an extention of Field so it should use trackwheelClick.

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to make your `BitmapField` focusable.

I just tried this:

```
    BitmapField LogoBmpField = new BitmapField(LOGO, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE) {
        protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {   
            System.out.println(" -- You clicked me! ");
            return true;
        }
    };
```

and it seems to work.

2) And to change the text on your button use
[setLabel()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ButtonField.html#setLabel%28java.lang.String%29)

```
btf1.setLabel("new button text");
```

Comment: Well spotted with the focusable style!

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    public LanguageSelector() {

        Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("normalarabflag.png");
        BitmapField LogoBmpField = new BitmapField(logoBitmap, BitmapField.FOCUSABLE | Field.FIELD_HCENTER) {
            protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {   
                System.out.println(" -- You clicked me! ");
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new SecoundScreen());
                Dialog.alert("Load Complete");
                return true;
            }
        };

        LabelField labelfield = new LabelField("Arabic ",Field.FIELD_HCENTER|LabelField.FOCUSABLE);

        VerticalFieldManager vrt=new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_WIDTH) {

            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

                super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());
                setExtent(Display.getWidth(),Display.getHeight());

            }
        };

        Font f=labelfield.getFont();
        int hight1=f.getAdvance(labelfield.getText());
        int k=labelfield.getPreferredHeight();

        int number=hight1/Display.getWidth()+1;
        int hight2=logoBitmap.getHeight();
        int padding=(Display.getHeight()-((number*k)+hight2))/2;

        if(padding>0) {
            LogoBmpField.setPadding(padding,0,0,0);
        }

        vrt.add(LogoBmpField);
        vrt.add(labelfield);

        add(vrt);
    }     
}
```

Comment: Post only relevant part to answer the question.

Comment: Code does not seem either very clear or very well thought out.  It also shows little understanding of BlackBerry UI complications, I would be careful about using this code in a production program.